# Smoothing spline seems to fit too precisely?

Tags: r, splines, smoothing

I am trying to fit some time series data to a smoothing spline in R. However, it seems like the spline is fitting the data too perfectly, meaning overfitting. I was trying to figure out what settings to change to try and adjust the level of smoothing. I don't want to manually set the $\lambda$ parameter, because it seems like that should automatically be set according to some metric. I believe the default is generalized cross-validation, so
that should work okay.

Here is some data and code. Can anyone tell me the correct way to apply the splines to the dataset.

I can manually change the number of *Knots*, but that seems a bit manual. I have a number of datasets to fit, so I don't want to manually fit the number of knots each time. Is there a better way to determine the penalty. I suppose having a twice differentiable function is optimal, so no sharp edges.

```
library(npreg)

y <- c(23.0, 27.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 22.0, 22.0, 21.0, 18.0, 16.0, 17.0, 17.0, 19.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 19.0, 18.0, 20.0, 19.0, 17.0, 21.0, 20.0, 16.0, 15.0, 16.0, 14.0, 14.0, 12.0, 14.0)

x <- c(1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008)

mod <- ss(x, y)
pred_y <-predict(mod, x)$y
plot(x,y)
lines(x, pred_y, lwd=2)
```

The corresponding picture is.

[image]

Comment: What is the default argument for the number of knots?

Comment: The number of knots is a hyperparameter. You can tune it.

Comment: @Galen yeah, I think it is using the entire dataset for the knots, so there are 30 knots. That seems like too much, but not sure how to get the system to automatically determine the number of knots.

Comment: @Galen Ahh, that makes sense. But how do I tune the knots? Like is that in a different function, or do I need to write a loop to try different numbers of knots and then estimate a criteria?

Comment: What is the purpose of this model? Is it to interpolate? If it is meant to forecast I wouldn't start with splines.

Comment: Yeah, so I want to do a smoothed interpolation--so not fitting all of the points exactly. Then I will compute the derivative at each data point, and use those derivatives to fit a differential equation. So I need the derivatives at each point.

Comment: You would probably want to specify one of df, spar or lambda in order to make the function smoother.

Comment: @Glen_b I will look into those arguments too. I need to figure out the proper metric or criterion to evaluate the smoothing? I can think of many metrics to impose smoothing, like penalizing total variation, or degrees of freedom. But I need a metric--besides just looking at the result--to tell me whether I have over-smoothed or undersmoothed. I will have to look for some articles on the topic. I suppose I could do "leave one out", and then take the average over the resulting curves. But I suppose there are other ways too.

Comment: You would need to then define what you mean by 'oversmooth' and 'undersmooth' for your application/needs, or you risk getting an accurate  answer to the wrong question.

Comment: @Glen_b yes, I was just looking at the Silverman book and some others, to understand the techniques. I am only a couple of chapters in, but seems so far like this is not a question that is considered--how smooth. Like many techniques use a moving window, or a fixed bandwidth, etc. And then the window size is tuned based on prediction task. But I am trying to look for similarity versus differences between time series--so more clustering. If I smooth to optimize the clustering, that could really mess up the structure of the underlying data instead of just denoising.

Comment: @Glen_b what I would like to do is smooth the data enough so that I can denoise it and get the derivatives along the curve. And then I can fit a differential equation to that curve. So I kinda need the smoothed curve to maintain some fidelity to the original.  If I assume that the original data $f$ is a corrupted version of the smooth line, then I can create a loss function with a squared error term for the reconstruction  $\hat{f}$, plus a penalty on the sharp jumps in the data, $\sum (f - \hat{f})^2 + \lambda \sum |\hat{f}_{i+1} - \hat{f}_{i}|$. I need to figure out how to tune $\lambda$.

Comment: @Glen_b The penalty has $i$ representing each data point in the data vector. So I am penalizing change between each adjacent point, so $i$ versus $i+1$. But there are different ways to generalize this, such penalizing the difference in probability between points based upon the quantiles of a gaussian or something.

Comment: Your suggested penalty doesn't seem to sufficiently directly relate to the specific thing you said you needed -- accuracy of *derivatives*. Unless your criterion will deliver sufficiently accurate derivatives for your needs (maybe it does, but you'd need to show it), this is pretty much what I was getting at by risking "an accurate answer to the wrong question". Does that penalty really do what you need?

Comment: @Glen_b yes, true. The objective function I defined ensures a curve that is smoother, where I can compute a derivative. In the original noisy function, I can't even compute a derivative because there are discontinuities at each point. The next thing is to figure out how to compute the "right" derivatives.

Comment: You may need to start with one or more plausible descriptions of the process you'd like to approximate and look at performance on those. Presumably you're interested in optimizing typical performance rather than trying to optimize based on the noise in one sample.

Comment: @Glen_b yep, I need to let the process I am trying to estimate determine the proper smoothness criterion. That is correct. Thanks for the advice there. I will think more about that now. I guess first I was trying to remember all the smoothing approaches, and now I can think about which smoothing approach matches the process I am trying to estimate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More specifically, you are right that something is being done to select the smoothing parameters for the spline and that by default this is GCV. It is known (from the spline / GAM literature) that GCV can undersmooth and I believe this is what you are seeing here.

Choosing another method, such as REML smoothness selection leads to a more reasonable fit:

```r
# reusing objects from your post
m_reml <- ss(x, y, method = "REML")
p_reml <- predict(m_reml, x)$y
plot(x, y)
lines(x, pred_y, col = "red", lwd = 2)
lines(x, p_reml, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
```

produces

[image]

As you have a variable that is ordered in time, there is the additional complication that if there is some signal that is contaminated by autoregressive noise, this violates the assumptions used to select the smoothing parameters and can lead you to over fit. One option in that case would be to model the autocorrelated noise:

```r
library("mgcv")
df <- data.frame(y = y, x = x)
m_gam <- gamm(y ~ s(x, k = 6), data = df, method = "REML",
              correlation = corAR1(form = ~ x))

p_gam <- predict(m_gam$gam, newdata = df)

plot(x, y)
lines(x, pred_y, col = "red", lwd = 2)
lines(x, p_reml, col = "blue", lwd = 2)
lines(x, p_gam, col = "green", lwd = 2)
```

[image]

In this instance it doesn't help (for some definition of "help") as the model has assigned all the variation to the autocorrelation process (the AR(1)) and the resulting trend is linear with some aspect of the model fit becoming no-positive definite - a sure sign that the model is over-fit or too complex. This often happens because a trend and an autocorrelation process like the AR(p) are not always identifiable from data

Comment: thanks so much for this detailed response. This is very helpful. I will keep in mind what you said about REML. The point about autocorrelation is also important. I am not as familiar with the `mgcv` package, but does the `gamm` command first remove the linear trend and then try to fit an AR(1) process? I imagine this linear trend is estimated and then the series is detrended before fitting the AR(1), but just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: It is interesting that the process fits the AR(1) process so well, but I get what you mean. So from the code it seems like it tried to fit up to AR(6), as per the $k$ parameter, but then columns 2-6 are all linearly dependent and hence the matrix is singular? Is that why the corresponding line is purely linear trend, since there is no trendiness left in the residuals to assign anywhere else.

Comment: Only an AR(1) was fitted in the correlation matrix of residuals; the `k` relates to the size of the basis expansion of `x`, which resulted in 5 columns (basis functions) being added to the model matrix plus a constant term for the intercept. This is basically a Generalised Least Squares-like model, except we're treating the smooth random effects, so the linear part of the basis and the intercept are in the model matrix while the other 4 basis functions are actually in the model matrix for the random effects. All parameters are being estimated simultaneously, so the AR(1) isn't estimated later

Comment: Ahh okay. I understand what you mean now. Thanks so much for your help on this question. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

The number of knots is a hyperparameter. You can tune it.

There are many [approaches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization#Approaches) although for time series you will need to be cautious about how you partition the data. See [this online textbook passage](https://otexts.com/fpp3/tscv.html) for guidance on splitting. Essentially, you'll have to sequentially break the data up into blocks.

Comment: Oh yes, I don't need to worry about data leakage, as in the Hyndman book. I don't have a test set that I am trying to evaluate on, in this case. But definitely something to keep in mind when I get to that part. Thanks.

Comment: @krishnab Okay. I am speculating that grid search with leave-one-out CV might be suitable since you don't appear to have lot of data. It might be worth looking up differentiation-specific smoothing methods (if you have not already).

Comment: yeah that makes sense. I can do that. In terms of penalties on the derivative, yeah I can include that. Usually I can penalize the difference between the values at $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$, with a tuning parameter. This is similar to total variation denoising, if you are familiar with signal processing. I get what you mean though, I think I have enough to go on now.

Comment: @kirshnab you mention that you have multiple datasets to fit. Are you expecting them to all have the same "number of knots"? If yes, consider holding out some of these datasets as test sets and using the rest as train sets to figure out a good parameter

Comment: @Shadi yes, that makes sense. Yeah, I am just working on preprocessing the data at this point, but you are correct as well as Galen. I will have to think of a way to hold out some datasets or hold out some observations, etc. Something like that makes sense.